# Showing $ (2/3)^{\log_{3/2}(n/n_0)} =n_0/n $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I read the following identity in the CLRS Introduction to Algorithms book, and I can't work out the computation.
$$
(2/3)^{\log_{3/2}(n/n_0)} =n_0/n
$$
I tried to expand the exponent using the division rule for logarithms and bring the factor with the negative power down as a denominator. I couldn't figure out what I could do next.

Comment: **Hint :** $\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Comment: Aah I see it now. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Applying the [hint given by Surb](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802928/help-with-an-identity-involving-logarithms/4802937#comment10214944_4802928) leads to

$$\left(\frac{1}{3/2}\right)^{\log_{3/2}(n/n_0)}
= \left(\frac{1^{\log_{3/2}(n/n_0)}}{\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^{\log_{3/2}(n/n_0)}}\right) = \frac{1}{\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^{\log_{3/2}(n/n_0)}} = \frac{1}{\dfrac{n}{n_0}} = \frac{n_0}{n},
$$ as desired.

Thanks Surb.

Comment: **Notice**: $a^{\log_a b}= b$.